# Can I use a smart switch for a separate light ceiling fan?

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

I’ve been searching for a very long time for this solution:

I’m replacing all of my light switches with smart switches. The switch in my room is a double switch - one switch controls the light, the other switch controls the ceiling fan. I cannot find a smart switch set that controls the light and fan separately. Sure, I can get two separate smart switches (that work like the current switch), but I want one of the switches to control the fan speed, and the other switch to control the light dimming. Is this possible?

Comment: "Product recommendation" or "shopping" questions are explicitly off-topic because the answer can change so quickly. I don't believe they're quite on-topic at [iot.se], but you may have better success in asking there and phrasing it along the lines of "how do people handle this situation?" instead of "is product 'x' available".

Comment: Are you tied to a specific system?

Answer (score 2):

You will need two separate switches.  One will control the lights, and one will control the fan.  When you do this, you use the pull chain on the fan to set it at the highest speed, and then the smart fan controller will adjust the speed.  And note that I said "fan controller".  Fan motors need a different type of dimming than a light bulb, so if you just get two light dimmers, the fan might not work like you want or could be noisy.  One example is this [Caseta Fan Control](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N1GXM38).  Other smart switch ecosystems will probably have something similar.

Of course, this all assumes that the fan has three wires going to it - a hot for the light, a hot for the fan, and a neutral.  Normally these will be black, red, and white, but wire colors can vary (could be two blacks and one white).

Comment: Heck, if you use a dumb fan controller, you use the pull chain to set the fan to its max speed and use the switch on the wall to control actual speed. ;)